# pandas / matplotlib: faceting bar plots

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, pandas

I am making a series of bar plots of data with two categorical variables and one numeric. What i have is the below, but what I would love to do is to facet by one of the categorical variables as with `facet_wrap` in `ggplot`. I have a somewhat working example, but I get the wrong plot type (lines and not bars) and I do subsetting of the data in a loop--that can't be the best way.

```
## first try--plain vanilla
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 100

## generate toy data
ind = np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], N)
cty = np.random.choice(['x','y','z'], N)
jobs = np.random.randint(low=1,high=250,size=N)

## prep data frame
df_city = pd.DataFrame({'industry':ind,'city':cty,'jobs':jobs})
df_city_grouped = df_city.groupby(['city','industry']).jobs.sum().unstack()
df_city_grouped.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,figsize=(9, 6))
```

This gives something like this:

```
  city industry  jobs
0    z        b   180
1    z        c   121
2    x        a    33
3    z        a   121
4    z        c   236
```

[image: firstplot]

However, what i would like to see is something like this:

```
## R code
library(plyr)
df_city<-read.csv('/home/aksel/Downloads/mockcity.csv',sep='\t')

## summarize
df_city_grouped <- ddply(df_city, .(city,industry), summarise, jobstot = sum(jobs))

## plot
ggplot(df_city_grouped, aes(x=industry, y=jobstot)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  facet_wrap(~city)
```

[image]

The closest I get with matplotlib is something like this:

```
cols =df_city.city.value_counts().shape[0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, cols, figsize=(8, 8))

for x, city in enumerate(df_city.city.value_counts().index.values):
    data = df_city[(df_city['city'] == city)]
    data = data.groupby(['industry']).jobs.sum()
    axes[x].plot(data)
```

[image]

So two questions:

1. Can I do bar plots (they plot lines as shown here) using the AxesSubplot object and end up with something along the lines of the facet_wrap example from `ggplot` example;
2. In loops generating charts such as this attempt, I subset the data in each. I can't imagine that is the 'proper' way to do this type of faceting?

Comment: why don't you just use `bar` in your loop?

Comment: @tcaswell, good suggestion. What is the trick for plotting bar plots? Both arguments seem to be required as numeric. Convert the categorical variable first? Is there a more canonical way?

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar

Comment: Sorry for an answer on an old question but I landed here from a google search.
Now you can use seaborn.FacetGrid see documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html or this tutorial https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second example here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/visualization.html#bar-plots

Anyway, you can always do that by hand, as you did yourself.

EDIT:
BTW, you can always use rpy2 in python, so you can do all the same things as in R.

Also, have a look at this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/rplot.html
I am not sure, but it should be helpful for creating plots over many panels, though might require further reading.

Comment: I suppose that is workable, but I really like them in separate panels, as `ggplot` does it, particularly as that is flexible as more dimensions is added. And the example of course doesn't like the data frame variables to be non-numeric. Do have a good way to work around that?

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for out of the box--without having to subset the data in each loop. All that remains is for me to understand the 'proper' way to plot categorical variables in a plot.

Comment: First link broken.

Answer (score 2):

@tcasell suggested the `bar` call in the loop. Here is a working, if not elegant, example.

```
## second try--facet by county

N = 100
industry = ['a','b','c']
city = ['x','y','z']
ind = np.random.choice(industry, N)
cty = np.random.choice(city, N)
jobs = np.random.randint(low=1,high=250,size=N)
df_city =pd.DataFrame({'industry':ind,'city':cty,'jobs':jobs})

## how many panels do we need?
cols =df_city.city.value_counts().shape[0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, cols, figsize=(8, 8))

for x, city in enumerate(df_city.city.value_counts().index.values):
    data = df_city[(df_city['city'] == city)]
    data = data.groupby(['industry']).jobs.sum()
    print (data)
    print type(data.index)
    left=  [k[0] for k in enumerate(data)]
    right=  [k[1] for k in enumerate(data)]

    axes[x].bar(left,right,label="%s" % (city))
    axes[x].set_xticks(left, minor=False)
    axes[x].set_xticklabels(data.index.values)

    axes[x].legend(loc='best')
    axes[x].grid(True)
    fig.suptitle('Employment By Industry By City', fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Comment: 1 subtle difference is that here all 3 plots have different scale, which makes it difficult to compare across panels

Comment: this is easily fixed by adding `sharey` to the `subplots` function like so : `plt.subplots(1, cols, figsize=(8, 8), sharey=True)`

Answer (score 1):

The [Seaborn library](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html), which is built on Matplotlib and could be considered a superset of it, has flexible and powerful plotting options for facet plots--they even use similar terminology to R.  Scroll down on [this page](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) for multiple examples.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across [`plotnine`](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that provides `ggplot2`-like interface in Python. Using `plotnine`, you can write your code as:

```py
from plotnine import *

# load your data

(ggplot(df_city_grouped, aes(x='industry', y='jobstot'))
 + geom_bar(stat='identity')
 + facet_wrap('~city'))
```