# faceting in loop--assigning df.plot to axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, facet, geopandas

Building on data from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613486/pandas-matplotlib-faceting-bar-plots) on faceting through looping, I was wondering if it was possible to call a `ax = df.plot(kind='bar')` and assign the thus generated `AxesSubplot` object to a specific axis position/coordinate? (like facet row 1, col 1, 2, 3, etc ... )?

The reason I am asking is not really for faceting bar plots as such, but for faceting map production using the `geopandas` library. If it worked with bar plots, it might also work with geopandas geodataframe.plot() calls. I can't plot a map from axes themselves, therefore I seem to need to go the other way around--get axes as a byproduct of a plot call, and then place that as appropriate in a grid.

Non-working example--the loop is really pseudo here; I don't move the axis index to plot a different panel each time (in fact, I overwrite the axes object from the subplots call). That is, though, what I would like to do--map the axis object generated from the plot call to the axes (coordinate space) from the subplots call).

```
N = 100
industry = ['a','b','c']
city = ['x','y','z']
ind = np.random.choice(industry, N)
cty = np.random.choice(city, N)
jobs = np.random.randint(low=1,high=250,size=N)
df_city =pd.DataFrame({'industry':ind,'city':cty,'jobs':jobs})

## how many panels do we need?
cols =df_city.city.value_counts().shape[0]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, cols, figsize=(8, 8))

for x, city in enumerate(df_city.city.value_counts().index.values):
    data = df_city[(df_city['city'] == city)]
    data = data.groupby(['industry']).jobs.sum()
    axes = data.plot(kind='bar')
    print type(axes)
    fig.suptitle('Employment By Industry By City', fontsize=20)

<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, the accepted answer in that other question is overly pessimistic about the chances of doing this with pandas.  How about this:

```
for ix, (key, group) in enumerate(df_city.groupby('industry')):
    ax = pyplot.subplot(1, 3, ix+1)
    group.groupby('city')['jobs'].sum().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel('industry: {}'.format(key))
```

With that you get:

[image]

The idea is to group by the variable that you want to separate subplots, and iterate over the groups.  For each group, use `pyplot.subplot` to target the desired subplot for each group and use another groupby on the group data to get the summary values to plot.  You can pass the `ax` argument to `DataFrame.plot` to tell it to plot into an existing axes object.  (I can't tell if you want them grouped by industry first and then city within each plot, or the other way around, but you just switch "industy" and "city" in the two `groupby` calls if you want it the other way around.)

In this version, the axes limits are not equalized across the subplots.  But the general idea can be polished to handle that.

Comment: clever solution that works with the specific problem presented, but not the underlying map problem. However, unfortunately, the `geopandas` plot interface doesn't accept the same keyword args, so `ax=ax` assignment appears non-kosher.

Comment: @ako: I added the `geopandas` tag to your question.  If geopandas' workings are critical to your question, it would probably be good to make an example that focuses on that (i.e., an example that actually uses geopandas).

Comment: you are probably right; FWIW since there were only a handful of questions tagged `geopandas` I cast it as a more general question of hooking up with subaxes objects because I thought that would increase likelihood of a response.